# mongodb query result without field name

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to get mongodb query results with only the values and not the field names. My query gives me the following result:

```
{
           "t_number" : 2508
},
{
           "t_number" : 2560
},
{
           "t_number" : 2599
}
```

Ideally I want the query result to be `[2508,2560,2599]`. Or if that is not possible, is it possible to get the query result as `[{2508},{2560},{2599}]`. I know that I can iterate over the result and change the format in my programming language. I am looking for a way to get that from mongodb and save some work.

Comment: Use aggregate with $unwind. another pipeline use $group with $push. db.col.aggregate([{$unwind: "$t_number"}, {$group: {_id: field, "t_number": {$push: "$t_number"} }}]). Try it.

Comment: Thanks. Aggregate gives the result closer to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't do it directly.

But this one liner could help you:

```
db.collection.find({},{_id:0, t_number:1}).toArray().map(function(ele) {return ele.t_number} );
```

Comment: does this result in [2508,2560,2599] being sent over the wire (as opposed to extracted application side)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible because mongodb returns only `JSON` Objects and according to http://www.json.org a JSON-Object is surrounded by curly brackets `{ }` and (if it is not empty) a value is allways indecated by a String (and seperated by a `:`).

Comment: MongoDB returns BSON objects

Comment: Wenn that's true. BSON is a binary representation of JSON so the rules of defining a valid object are the same.

Comment: An array is an object and it is also a data type in BSON, in theory MongoDB could return a transformed result with only the array but such funcitonality does not yet exist