# remove a field from mongodb query result in golang

Tags: json, mongodb, go, bson, mongo-go-driver

This is my function from mongodb-go-driver:

```
func MongodbFindOne(key, value string) bson.M {
    var result bson.M
    opts := options.FindOne().SetShowRecordID(false)
    _ = Collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{key: value}, opts).Decode(&result)
    return result
}
```

The function works very good but i get `_id` field in the result. I know the mongodb query to exclude a field from query result, But i don't know how to use it with `FindOne()` function:

From [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/can-we-remove-id-from-mongodb-query-result):

> db.removeIdDemo.find({},{_id:0});

From [mongodb query result without field name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23810768/7355000)

> db.collection.find({},{_id:0, t_number:1}).toArray().map(function(ele) {return ele.t_number} );

From [remove _id from mongo result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601614/7355000) (nodejs):

> ```
> app.get('/itesms', function(req, res) {   items.find({}, { _id: 0 }).toArray(function (err, array) {
>     res.send(array);   }) });
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To exclude fields from the result, use a projection. Use [`FindOneOptions.SetProjection()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.4.1/mongo/options#FindOneOptions.SetProjection) to set the projection.

To specifically exclude the `_id` field:

```
err = c.FindOne(ctx,
    bson.M{key: value},
    options.FindOne().SetProjection(bson.M{"_id": 0}),
).Decode(&result)
```

Comment: When I exclude _id, Im still getting id as 000000.... in the result struct. So how to remove that?

Comment: @Poujhit If your Go type (struct) holds an objectID, it will be initialized to its zero value. If you don't want that, remove the objectID field from your Go struct.